# Opentok Not able to subscribe to video in IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, opentok

We have a hybrid app developed using Ionic Cordova. We have a video calling feature developed using Opentok.
The ionic version is 3.
The Opentok version is  3.0
The Video subscribing is not happening in IOS for the receiving user, it works fine in Android and Web.
The calling user is able to see both the videos. i.e able to publish and subscribe. But the receiving user can only see his own video. i.e it is only able to publish and not able to subscribe.

The streamcreated event is not getting triggered. If we publish the Video again from the calling user, it is able to subscribe.

```
this.session.on("streamCreated", e => {
  debugger;// Doesn't get triggered

  }
});
this.session.on("streamDestroyed", e => this.onStreamDestroyed(e));
```

Are we missing anything. Any help will be greatly appreciated